# Azure Functions are not showing in Azure Function App

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I have azure functions soution which are tageted to .net 4.6.1 framework.
I deployed soutions using CI pipeline. Have options like Nuget Restore, Build Soution, Archive files and Publish Artifact: drop.
Archive File config:
[image]

Publish Artifact: drop  -
[image]

Below is the configuration i did in Release Pipeline.
[image]

Nothing is getting updated from Release Pipeline in fuction app.
In Function App shwoing No Results for Functions. If i publish manually all functions are getting updated correctly in Azure Function App.

Image from Kudu:
[image]

b folder is empty.
bin folder contains this data
[image]

Getting "2022-08-16T06:11:24.4977098Z : Deployment successful." message in Kudu.

Comment: Did you check the logs of the deploy to QA ?

Comment: I didn't get a path for logs to verify. Still looking for path location as i am completely new in Azure.

Comment: I verified in Azure Function App Kudu, there are no function which i am looking for. Looks like problem in Pipeline where ZIP files getting generated after Run Pipeline. ZIP files getting created at 'D:\a\_tasks\ArchiveFiles_d8b84976-e99a-4b86-b885-4849694435b0\2.206.0\7zip\7z.exe a -tzip -mx=5 D:\a\1\a\378599.zip @D:\a\_temp\p1sfq55b1wc', not sure how to verify ZIP and all functions are included in it. When i compiled my soulutions, all functions are seen in functionsSdk.out file.

Comment: Could you please share the tasks steps how you deployed?

Comment: @HariKrishna, did more analysis and found that notinng is updated from Release Pipeline. If i publish manually all functions are getting updated correctly. i am updating original post for more clarity.

Comment: What is the CI Publish Output and check what files you've added to the zip!

Comment: @HariKrishna, how and where  to check that?
Do i need to check under Pipeline or Release path. Could you please guide me.

Comment: @HariKrishna, CI Publish output is Root folder or file to archive : $(Build.BinariesDirectory), Archive Type is zip and Archive file to Create : $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip